# I'm having problems with this QUICKSORT function, can anyone see whats wrong with it?

Tags: quicksort, solidity

I'm trying to do a lottery smart contract in solidity but my code runs out of gas almost every time that I execute a function to chose the winner. When debugging it, I found that it blocks when it pass through this other function QuickSort, but I don't know why. Someone have any clue?

```
function quickSort(uint[qntNumbers] memory tab, uint left, uint right) private {
    uint i = left;
    uint j = right;
    uint mid = tab[left + (right - left) / 2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (tab[i] < mid) i++;
        while (mid < tab[j]) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            (tab[i], tab[j]) = (tab[j], tab[i]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(tab, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(tab, i, right);

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the amount of gas you pass to the function and a sample input? We need to be able to reproduce the error to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `add if(i==j) return;` as below:

```
function quickSort(uint[qntNumbers] memory tab, uint left, uint right) private {
    uint i = left;
    uint j = right;
    if (i == j) return;
    uint mid = tab[left + (right - left) / 2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (tab[i] < mid) i++;
        while (mid < tab[j]) j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            (tab[i], tab[j]) = (tab[j], tab[i]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(tab, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(tab, i, right);

}
```